# Repeat audio on Chrome/Firefox mobile when phone is off

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, mobile-browser, howler.js

I wrote a small language learning app for my own use which plays audio recordings with howlerjs. The audio is played in a loop, when the end is reached, it just restarts until the user intervenes.

**To the Problem**: When I turn off my phone (standby) the audio file still plays - like it should - but is not restarted ones the end is reached.

Is there a JavaScript trick I can use to restart it even when my phone is off? Or can I change a setting in Chrome/Firefox to stop Chrome/Firefox from preventing a restart?

Comment: What did you try exactly? Using `loop` works for me on Firefox and Chrome for Android even when screen is locked. https://jsfiddle.net/vbLm1ty5/

Comment: I restarted the audio via code. After a quick google search, I saw that howlerjs has a loop attribute. When I set that to true, it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see, that howlerjs has a loop attribute, one can set to true. I always restarted the audio again via code, when it was finished. Thanks to [Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) it works now.